# strcpy and strcmp, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, strcmp, strcpy

User should enter a few strings and input space as string when he is done.
Code should return longest and shortest word entered.

strcmp always returns -1... what am i doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char S[100][20];
    int I = 0;
    do {
            cout << "Enter text:" << endl;
            cin.getline(S[I],100);
    } while (I < 19 && strcmp(S[I++],""));
    char Max[100], Min[100];
    strcpy(Max, S[0]);
    strcpy(Min, S[0]);
    for (int J = 1; J < I; J++) {
        if (strcmp(S[J], Max) == 1)
            strcpy(Max, S[J]);
        if (strcmp(S[J], Min) == -1)
            strcpy(Min, S[J]);
    }
    cout << "Max = " << Max << endl;
    cout << "Min = " << Min << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` does not report which string is longer or shorter.  Did you intend to use `strlen`?

Comment: I know how to make it work with strlen, but assignment said to use strcmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a couple of things:

- variables should be lowercase;
- you are defining your array of string with wrong length (should be `s[20][100]`);
- in your `while` cycle, you should go 'till `i < 20`;
- the last string in your array will always be the empty string (hence: `s_min` will be always empty);
- `strcmp` compares strings, it doesn't tell you which one is the longest. You should use `strlen` for that...

Here the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char s[20][100];
  int i = 0;
  do {
    cout << "Enter text:" << endl;
    cin.getline(s[i], 100);
  } while (i < 20 && strcmp(s[i++],""));

  char s_max[100], s_min[100];
  strcpy(s_max, s[0]);
  strcpy(s_min, s[0]);
  for (int j = 1; j < i-1; j++) {
    if (strlen(s[j]) > strlen(s_max))
      strcpy(s_max, s[j]);
    if (strlen(s[j]) < strlen(s_min))
      strcpy(s_min, s[j]);
  }

  cout << "Max = " << s_max << endl;
  cout << "Min = " << s_min << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variables should be lowercase? That is entirely irrelevant, at best, and at odds with typical practice for C++, at worst.

Comment: it is irrelevant for the compiler, it is important for code readability. I sincerely get an headache when reading sources that don't follow standards. just my opinion, though..

Comment: mm, so if we talk about code redability, we should also consider that variable should have significant name, so `char strings[20][100]` instead of `char s[20][100]`. Anyway, in my opinion it doesn't have such relevance in this context, when developing a large scale application surely, but this is just an exercise.

Comment: Thank you, although I already had it working with strlen. The assignment said to use strcmp, so that why I used it instead of strlen, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: okay, that makes sense... I completely agree with @dtumaykin (and there are so many other things to say about code clarity, using constants or `#define` for example), but uppercase variables are just something I can't stand...

Answer (score 2):

Try use 
char S[20][100];
instead of
char S[100][20];

Answer (score 1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/):

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings: A zero value indicates that both strings are equal. A value
>   greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not
>   match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than
>   zero indicates the opposite.

It shouldn't be 1 or -1, try testing with >/< 0. Also, test if the strings read from stdio ends up in '\0' and eventually add it(getline should), because strcmp makes use of it.

Also, array size if wrong. Should be `char S[20][100]`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to >/< 0, and fixed the array size.
But if I enter John, David and Leo for strings, first strcmp will still return -1, although it should obviously return positive value.
And I don't know how to check for /0.

Comment: getline() adds null char to the end -- looking up for the rest now

Comment: works for me on VS2010, which compiler are you using? also, mind decreasing I, when you're done with input - the last string shouldn't be considered

Comment: I'm using Bloodshed Dev-C++ (this is MinGW/GCC i think). Yeah, "I" should be decreased by one. I made it work using strlen, but using strcmp still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try to use the code @StefanoP proposes here. If neither it works well, try to update or change IDE. Unfortunately I'm familar with Dev-C++(used it at school) and I can say it isn't *khm* the best choice. Try VS2010 Express C++, it's free and way more decent then Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're declaring your array backwards; it looks like you really want `char S[20][100]`.
2. You need to compare using `< 0` and `> 0`, since `strcmp()` doesn't guarantee that it will return you a 1 or a -1.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp):

   > The **`strcmp()`** and **`strncmp()`** functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if *s1* (or the first *n* bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than *s2*.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare the strings in your code but your question says you want to compare length. Use `strlen` on a null-terminated strings to compare lengths. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) is the reference. Better yet, if what you're writing is C++ code (as it is tagged), you're already using the standard library, so go ahead and use `std::string`. This sounds like it should be tagged homework, however, in which case I assume you can't use the `std::string` class.